# SQL Transform duplicates to one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I’m having a table named TBL which has an id, code, date

When i’m using this query :

```
SELECT * FROM TBL 
WHERE TBL.id=“1527”
```

I’m getting this back

| id | code | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1527 | 26181 | 16/03/21 |
| 1527 | 15182 | 05/09/20 |

How can I turn it to this?(by query)

| id | code |
| --- | --- |
| 1527 | 26181,15182 |

Glad for any help

Comment: Which DBMS product you are using? Oracle? Sql Server?

Comment: Hi, I’m using Sql server

Comment: Please post sql server version also?

Comment: Why do you want to store multiple values in a single field? That's a SQL Anti-Pattern, *generally* indicative of a faulty design. Avoid comma delimited values whenever possible.

Comment: T-SQL now has the STRING_AGG() function which is available from SQL Server 2017. This function does pretty much the same thing as MySQL’s GROUP_CONCAT() function (with some minor differences).

Comment: How can I use it to achieve the requested result?

Comment: @shalevsror, Which version of SQL Server you are using?

Comment: Follow the examples in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005) In particular this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40692104/14868997

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
SELECT Id,STRING_AGG(code,',')  WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY Id ASC)  AS
Code FROM tbl
GROUP BY Id
```

Also, you can try this:

```
SELECT  id
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(code AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM tbl 
         WHERE id= t.id
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') List_Output
FROM tbl t
GROUP BY id
```